# Save cell changes in threaded comment VB

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to "Save" the previous info from the cell in a Threaded Comment when i change the value.
This script does that if a cell is empty. If a cell is not empty, then i would like it to save the last value in a threaded comment, not replacing the old comment, but making it into a discussion like it is supposed to be.

Can anybody help me with that? Attached is my code that makes a threaded comment.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const sRng As String = "A5:AQ155" ' change as required
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String
Dim sCmt As String
Dim iLen As Long

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target

        sNew = .Value2
        Application.Undo
        sOld = .Value2
        .Value2 = sNew

        Application.EnableEvents = True

        sCmt = "Sist endra: " & Format$(Now, "dd Mmm YYYY hh:nn:ss") & " av " & Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Tidligere info: " & sOld


        If .CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then
            .AddCommentThreaded sCmt
        Else
            .AddCommentThreaded sCmt
        End If

        With .CommentThreaded.Shape.TextFrame
            .AutoSize = True
            .Characters(Start:=iLen + 1).Insert IIf(iLen, vbLf, "") & sCmt
        End With

    End With

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Try reading the description of a tag before adding it to your question. The description for the VB.NET tag EXPLICITLY states that it is not for VBA questions. This is obviously a VBA question so now I have wasted my time opening a question in a tag I am watching because you don't know what language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It should just about do what you want although it uses the Note rather than the Comment. The new "Note" equals and replaces the former "Comment". Soo how you like it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 199

    Const sRng      As String = "A5:AQ155"      ' change as required
    Dim sOld        As String
    Dim sNew        As String
    Dim sCmt        As String
    Dim iStart      As Integer                  ' first character position
    Dim iEnd        As Integer                  ' lastcharacter position

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Target.Cells(1)
            sNew = .Value2
            
            Application.Undo
            sOld = .Value2                      ' get previous value
            .Value2 = sNew
    
            On Error Resume Next
            With .Comment
                sCmt = .Text                    ' get previous Note
                .Delete
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            If Len(sCmt) Then sCmt = vbLf & sCmt
            sCmt = "Sist endra: " & Format$(Now, "dd Mmm YYYY hh:nn:ss") & " av " & _
                   Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Tidligere info: " & sOld & sCmt

            With .AddComment(sCmt)
                Do
                    iEnd = iEnd + 1
                    iStart = InStr(iEnd, .Text, " av ", vbTextCompare) + 4
                    If iStart = 4 Then Exit Do
                    iEnd = InStr(iStart, .Text, Chr(10))
                    If iEnd = 0 Then iEnd = Len(.Text)
                    .Shape.TextFrame.Characters(iStart, iEnd - iStart).Font.Bold = True
                Loop
            End With
    
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The little game at the end which boldens the user name is intended to show how you might identify and modify  part of the comment's text.